# Plugins Not Loading In SPA packaged using 'quasar build'

Tags: build, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I have  a project that is built upon the laravel/quasar frameworks.

I have added the Quasar 'Loading' plugin to my front end and this works fine when I spin up the Quasar Dev server. However, when I do a Quasar Build to create my SPA the Loading plugin does not appear when it should and I get the following error...
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')**

I recently performed 'npm install force' on my quasar project and I suspect that this has resulted in the build issue. However I am not 100% about this. I have tried rolling back relevant dependencies and I get the same error. I have even tried copying my src folder into a clean quasr-cli install. Same error.

I executed 'quasar build' on the command line.
I expected the SPA to behave exactly like its equivalent vie the quasar dev server.
What actually happens is the SPA behaves just like it should with the exception that the Loading plugin does not appear when it should and a non-fatal error appears in the console.